# How to understand the action of functions of Pauli Matrices on qubits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information

$\renewcommand{\ket}[1]{\left \lvert #1 \right \rangle}$
In the attached photo, my professor has evaluated the action of the exponential of the x and y Pauli matrices on z-basis eigenstates, and there is also a phase attached to the operator of pi/4. Can somebody explain how did the professor make these evaluations? I tried a lot trying to visualise this through Bloch vectors but to no avail. Any sort of help will be much appreciated :)

\begin{align}
\exp \left( i \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_x \right) \ket{0}
&= \frac{\ket{0} + i \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\exp \left( i \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_x \right) \ket{1}
&= \frac{i \ket{0} + \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\exp \left( -i \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_y \right) \ket{0}
&= \frac{\ket{0} + \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\exp \left( i \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_x \right) \ket{1}
&= \frac{-\ket{0} + \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the exponential of a matrix?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]! In future, you should use MathJaX to enter equations rather than posting images.  [Here's a tutorial on how to do so.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  Please edit your question to correct this.

Comment: Think of $\exp(i \sigma_k \theta)$ as rotations around the axis $\sigma_k$ of an angle $\theta$ in the Bloch sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems he used this formula
(see [Pauli matrices - Exponential of a Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector))
$$\exp(ia(\hat{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}))
= I \cos a + i(\hat{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}) \sin a$$

where $a$ is an angle, $I$ is the $2\times 2$ unit matrix,
$\hat{n}$ is a 3-dimensional vector of length $1$,
and $\hat{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$ is short for the scalar
product $n_x\sigma_x+n_y\sigma_y+n_z\sigma_z$.

For example, for proving the first two formulas
you use the above equation
with $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $(n_x,n_y,n_z)=(1,0,0)$
to first calculate
$$\begin{align}
\exp(i\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_x)
&=I \cos\frac{\pi}{4}
 + i\sigma_x \sin\frac{\pi}{4} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 +i\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1&i\\i&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
and then apply this operator to $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

The most general way to evaluate such problems is to express the states on which the operator is acting in terms of eigenstates of that operator. This method can then be used for arbitrary operators and arbitrary states.

To start, we note that $\hat{x}$ and $f(\hat{x})$ have the same eigenstates for any operator $\hat{x}$, where the eigenstates have eigenvalues $x_i$ for operator $\hat{x}$ and eigenvalues $f(x_i)$ for operator $f(\hat{x})$.

In the first line, for example, we need to find the eigenstates of $\exp(i\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_x)$, so we can thus use the eigenstates of $\sigma_x$. The eigenstates of $\sigma_x$, in the $z$-basis, are $|\pm\rangle=(|0\rangle\pm|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, with eigenvalues $\pm 1$. We can thus always write
$$\sigma_x\left(\alpha|+\rangle+\beta|-\rangle\right)=\alpha|+\rangle-\beta|-\rangle$$ for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and similarly
$$\exp(i\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_x)\left(\alpha|+\rangle+\beta|-\rangle\right)=\alpha\exp[i\frac{\pi}{4}(+1)]|+\rangle+\exp[i\frac{\pi}{4}(-1)]\beta|-\rangle.$$ All that's left to do is to find the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the given state $|0\rangle$ can be expressed in terms of the states $|\pm\rangle$, then the calculation is immediate.

This technique can be used for any of the problems listed in the question and for many more general problems that do not involve Pauli matrices. For Pauli matrices, there are simpler techniques because the exponential of a Pauli matrix is straightforward to obtain.